# We lost the data by 12 hours

Tags: meaning

What would it mean:

> We lost the data by 12 hours.
>
> We missed it by 12 hours.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Peter. it would be useful if you edited your question to tell us about the situation that you would like to describe. As it stands, the first sentence doesn't make sense (the word "by" is incompatible with the context), and the second sentence might be used if you were very late for a flight.

Comment: Yes, this.  Perhaps you were expecting the first one to mean "We lost 12 hours of data", or "We lost 12 hours' worth of data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We lost the data by 12 hours" **might** mean "we were 12 hours to late to collect the data" perhaps because we started tryign to get the data too late. More context is really needed here to get the intended meaning.

This **might** have been used for "we lost 12 hours of data": but that would be a  non-standard and confusing usage.

"We missed it by 12 hours" means that some deadline or connection was not made by a margin of 12 hours. It could be a time to accomplish something, or a train to get on, or any of various other things with a specific time attached. Without context, one cannot say more precisely.